# Looping through links with Python paginated api works, but only by timeout error?

Tags: python, api, pagination

I'm new to python, but I don't see much information on Stackoverflow in regards to paginating with the links method. The loop works perfectly in that it pulls all the data I want, but it only breaks until there's a timeout error when my Mac falls asleep. Sometimes it runs for 2 hours until my Mac sleeps. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to retrieve this data? Here is my python script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = []

url = "https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCQJVAXWHB23WBNIG7TWEWHWUGGB6HWBC2ASPF5HMSADO5R5UKI4T7SD/trades"
querystring = {"limit":"200"}

try:
    while True:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)


        data = response.json()
        res += data['_embedded']['records']

        if "href" not in data['_links']['next']:
            break
        
        url = data['_links']['next']['href']

except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception:", ex)

df = pd.json_normalize(res)



df.to_csv('stellar_t7sd_trades.csv')
```

It returns with the following:

> Exception: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(60, 'Operation timed
> out'))

But it returns the desired data into the csv file.

Is there a problem with my loop in that it doesn't properly break when It's done returning the data? Just trying to figure out a way so it doesn't run for 2 hours, but other than that, I get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a break after n number of loop iterations. This only works because I know exactly how many iterations of the loop will pull the data I need.

```
res = []

url = "https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GCQJVAXWHB23WBNIG7TWEWHWUGGB6HWBC2ASPF5HMSADO5R5UKI4T7SD/trades"
querystring = {"limit":"200"}

n = 32
try:
    while n > 0:                      #True:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)

        n-=1

        data = response.json()
        res += data['_embedded']['records']

        if "href" not in data['_links']['next']:
            break

        elif n==32:
            break

        url = data['_links']['next']['href']
        

except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception:", ex)

df = pd.json_normalize(res)


df.to_csv('stellar_t7sd_tradestest.csv')
```